# Tabulator Nested Row

Tags: tabulator

I was wondering if it's possible to have a nested data tree where the child row has different headers that the parent row.

E.g.

Parent row has the following headers: Make, Model, SellDate, Warranty
The data type for the headers above are: String, String, Date, Boolean

The child row will have the following headers: Warranty Start Date, Warranty End Date, Type of Warranty
The data type for the headers above are: Date, Date, String

So I would like to create something like this:

> Make, Model, Selldate, Warranty
>     BMW, S3, 13-DEC-2017, Yes
>      13-DEC-2017,  13-DEC-2010, Labour & Parts

Answer (score 0):

I just got finished writing this same thing.  You can accomplish this with a combination of Nested Data and Row Formatters.

On your outer table configuration, specify:

```
dataTree: true,
rowFormatter: childRowFormatter,
```

Then, for the rowFormatter function, you can specify something like the below (following the lead from Tabulator's own Nested Tables example):

```
function childRowFormatter(row) {
    // skip if not a child/nested data row - let main table rows render as usual
    if (!row.getTreeParent())
        return;

    var rowEl = row.getElement();
    var parentChildData = row.getTreeParent().getData()._children;

    // only generate a new table for the first row of child data
    if (
        row.getPrevRow().getIndex() !== row.getTreeParent().getIndex() || 
        row.getPrevRow().getPosition() < 0
    ) {
        rowEl.remove();
        // set row element to empty element without size
        row._row.element = document.createElement('span');
        return;
    }

    // remove generated cell elements
    row._row.deleteCells();

    // create and style holder elements
    var holderEl = document.createElement("div");
    var tableEl = document.createElement("div");

    holderEl.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
    holderEl.style.padding = "10px 30px 10px 10px";
    holderEl.style.background = "#ddd";
    holderEl.appendChild(tableEl);

    // replace with holder
    rowEl.appendChild(holderEl);

    // create the new table
    var subTable = new Tabulator(tableEl, {
        data: parentChildData,
        columns: [
            { ... },
            ...
        ],
        dataTree: true,
        dataTreeStartExpanded: true,
        rowFormatter: childRowFormatter,
    });
}
```

**EDIT**: I updated my code after realizing it was a bit more intricate than first revealed.  Be cautious, as this code uses some undocumented properties and methods that weren't meant to be exposed to the developer.